# Unable to change class name of SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to change the class applied on an SVG with the click of a button. The code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p19rnmev/) .

My SVG looks like:

```
<svg id="test" class="fill" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="200px" >
      <path id="path22276" d="m500 81c-41-6-110-35-110-46 0-6 32 6 48 19 8 5 53 12 101 14 78 4 93 1 144-22 32-14 60-26 64-26 8 0-37 34-62 47-28 15-131 22-185 14z"/>
</svg>
```

I tried both the below code :

```
  document.getElementById("test").className = "halffill";
  document.querySelector("svg.fill").setAttribute("class","halffill");
```

I tested the same javascript code against a normal div tag. It worked fine. Is there some restriction on SVG? Please help me figure this out.

Comment: if you open your console, you'd see the error. Add `window.deFill = deFill;` under your function. I think the problem is with JSFiddle, as your code works in codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWoBaw

Comment: @Pjetr I did not understand what you meant by adding `window.deFill = deFill;`.  I can't understand why it failed in jsfiddle

Comment: I added some comments, maybe it's clearer now? http://jsfiddle.net/p19rnmev/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the javascript **load type** was set to `onload` that made the function call on load of the body instead of `onclick` of the button.

**Solution**: You can see a gear icon on the top-right of javascript section. Click on it and change the **load type** to **No wrap -in** **<head>**

Comment: What gear icon? This question is not tagged with anything that has a gear icon or a javascript section.

Comment: @0aslam0 has provided a link to his [code](http://jsfiddle.net/p19rnmev/) . There you can find gear icon. The gear icon refers to settings. Also you can find various sections(javascript, html, css).

Answer (score 33):

The `className` property on an SVG element has a different definition from the `className` property of an HTML element.

In HTML, `className` is a string.  In SVG it is an `SVGAnimatedString` object.  That's why you can't just do `svgElement.className = "halffill"`.

However, the second line (using `setAttribute()`) should work.

Answer (score 11):

The Version with `setAttribute` works for me. For `className`, you need `baseVal` in SVG:

```
document.getElementById("test").className.baseVal = "halffill";
```

Comment: why do we need that baseVal ?

Comment: although it worked for me , but i am curious to know the reason.

Comment: See my answer.  In SVG `className` is an `SVGAnimatedString` (not a string). `SVGAnimatedString` has two main properties `baseVal` and `animVal`.

Answer (score 6):

The thing is that javascript doesn't update in source code. You need to check the change in the inspect mode. First one didn't work for me either but the second one works.

```
document.querySelector("svg.fill").setAttribute("class","halffill");
```

Click on the button that is intended to change the name of the class and then go to inspect mode and check the class name of *svg* tag

**Note** : To go to inspect mode right click anywhere on the screen and click on *Inspect* or use ctrl + shift + I in google chrome in windows.

Comment: I did check in inspect mode in chrome. But it is not changing for me.

Comment: The problem was the javascript **load type** was set to **onload** that made the function call on load of the body instead of onclick of the button. Solution: You can see a gear icon on the top-right of javascript section. Click on it and change the **load type** to **No wrap -in <head>**

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use the classList property:

document.getElementById("test").classList.add("halffill");

Answer (score 1):

You can use this util functions when you want to play with any html element classes:

```
let SVGAnimatedString = function () {}
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  SVGAnimatedString = window.SVGAnimatedString
}

export function convertToArray (value) {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    value = value.split(' ')
  }
  return value
}

/**
 * Add classes to an element.
 * This method checks to ensure that the classes don't already exist before adding them.
 * It uses el.className rather than classList in order to be IE friendly.
 * @param {object} el - The element to add the classes to.
 * @param {classes} string - List of space separated classes to be added to the element.
 */
export function addClasses (el, classes) {
  const newClasses = convertToArray(classes)
  let classList
  if (el.className instanceof SVGAnimatedString) {
    classList = convertToArray(el.className.baseVal)
  } else {
    classList = convertToArray(el.className)
  }
  newClasses.forEach((newClass) => {
    if (classList.indexOf(newClass) === -1) {
      classList.push(newClass)
    }
  })
  if (el instanceof SVGElement) {
    el.setAttribute('class', classList.join(' '))
  } else {
    el.className = classList.join(' ')
  }
}

/**
 * Remove classes from an element.
 * It uses el.className rather than classList in order to be IE friendly.
 * @export
 * @param {any} el The element to remove the classes from.
 * @param {any} classes List of space separated classes to be removed from the element.
 */
export function removeClasses (el, classes) {
  const newClasses = convertToArray(classes)
  let classList
  if (el.className instanceof SVGAnimatedString) {
    classList = convertToArray(el.className.baseVal)
  } else {
    classList = convertToArray(el.className)
  }
  newClasses.forEach((newClass) => {
    const index = classList.indexOf(newClass)
    if (index !== -1) {
      classList.splice(index, 1)
    }
  })
  if (el instanceof SVGElement) {
    el.setAttribute('class', classList.join(' '))
  } else {
    el.className = classList.join(' ')
  }
}
```