# How to declare types of props of SVG component? [React, TypeScript and Webpack]

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, webpack

Basically, what I want to do is to import an SVG icon to my react component and add props to it. Like `size="24px"` to make it more flexible as a component. Or make it editable with CSS by adding `className` prop (so I could add e.g. hover prop to it).
As it's my first time using TypeScript with Webpack, I'm being confused about how should I declare types for SVG element and I get an error (shown below)

As there are many ways of include SVG I decided to import it as a ReactComponent.

menu-icon.svg

```
<svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path fill="currentColor" fillRule="evenodd" d="M4.5 5h15a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-15a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1zm0 6h15a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-15a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1zm0 6h15a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-15a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1z"></path>
</svg>
```

header.tsx (here I want my svg icon)

```
import React from 'react';
import MenuIcon from '../assets/menu-icon.svg';

const Header: React.SFC = () => {
  return (
    <header className="c-header u-side-paddings">
      <MenuIcon className="c-header__icon" />  // <-- className prop doesn't match provided type
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

index.d.ts (so the .svg file can be treated as a component)

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  import React = require('react');
  export const ReactComponent: React.SFC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

Adding `className` prop to MenuIcon SVG Component causes an error:

```
(JSX attribute) className: string
Type '{ className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

#### My understanding so far

- I could just wrap svg component inside a div, and add a `className` to it like that: `<div className="c-header__icon"><MenuIcon/></div>` but I feel like it's an inelegant solution and not really a good practice
- I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37949156/9212198) that SVG props aren't strings, cuz they're an `SVGAnimatedString` objects. So:
- I tried to create .tsx file instead of .svg (I wouldn't need `index.d.ts` file then), but it works only if `className`'s type is `string`. Also I'm not sure if it's a good practice to store SVG icons in files with different extension that `.svg`. In my opinion it's not good for clarity. If I'm wrong, tell me what actually good practices are, please. Here's the example:

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    interface MenuIcon {
      className?: SVGAnimatedString;
    }
    
    export class MenuIcon extends React.PureComponent<MenuIcon> {
      render() {
        return (
          <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path fill="currentColor" fillRule="evenodd" d="M4.5 5h15a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-15a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1zm0 
 6h15a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-15a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1zm0 6h15a.5.5 0 1 1 0 1h-15a.5.5 0 1 1 0-1z"></path>
    </svg>
        );
      }
    }
```

I feel like I'm in lack of some basics, It's just really hard for me to figure out what should I focus on, as there are several topics combined

Answer (score 22):

I've been facing this problem, and this solution worked fine for me:

```js
declare module "*.svg" {
   import { FC, SVGProps } from "react";
   const content: FC<SVGProps<SVGElement>>;
   export default content;
}
```

Besides, I'm using [@svgr/webpack](https://github.com/gregberge/svgr/tree/master/packages/webpack) as SVG loader along with Next.js

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly, BTW can you precise your svgr configuration for Next.js + TypeScript? I am wondering if I need to use any typescript option for svgr. Thanks!

Comment: add it on index.d.ts in the root folder of your typescript project

Comment: if you add `declare module "*.svg"` definition but typescript doesn't detect the type, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/75136709/11190169

Answer (score 13):

```
import React, { SVGProps } from 'react' 

// SVGElement props
type TSVGElementProps = SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>
```

Comment: Thanks but out of curiosity, why is `SVG` declared twice in `SVGSVGElement`?

Comment: @EkanemEno here is the official docs from MDN:  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement  

The SVGSVGElement interface provides access to the properties of <svg> elements, as well as methods to manipulate them. This interface contains also various miscellaneous commonly-used utility methods, such as matrix operations and the ability to control the time of redraw on visual rendering devices.

Comment: With SVGElement I get error types of property ref are incompatible on the svg tag. With SVGSVGElement it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can parameterize svgs for easy JSX.Element level customization via global abstraction. How? Use React's FC. Try implementing the following:

- Create the following interface

```
interface SvgIconConstituentValues {
    strokeColor?: string;
    strokeWidth?: string;
    strokeWidth2?: string;
    strokeWidth3?: string;
    strokeFill?: string;
    fillColor?: string;
    fillColor2?: string;
    fillColor3?: string;
    fillColor4?: string;
    fillColor5?: string;
    fillColor6?: string;
    fillColor7?: string;
    imageWidth?: string;
    imageHeight?: string;
    width?: string;
    height?: string;
    rotateCenter?: number;
    className?: string;
    className2?: string;
    className3?: string;
    className4?: string;
    className5?: string;
}

export default SvgIconConstituentValues;
```

- import `SvgIconConstituentValues` into a tsx file
- import `{ FC }` from React into the same tsx file

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import SvgIconConstituentValues from 'types/svg-icons';

// FC can be parameterized via Abstraction
```

- create an `SvgIcon` interface that extends `FC` and `SvgIconConstituentValues`

```
export interface SvgIcon extends FC<SvgIconConstituentValues> {}
```

- abstract the properties of an svg via parametrization with `SvgIcon` as follows

```
export const ArIcon: SvgIcon = ({
    width = '8.0556vw',
    height = '8.0556vw',
    strokeColor = `stroke-current`,
    strokeWidth = '2',
    fillColor = 'none',
    fillColor2 = `fill-primary`,
    rotateCenter = 0,
    className = ` antialiased w-svgIcon max-w-svgIcon`,
    className2 = ` stroke-current`,
    className3 = ` fill-primary`
}): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <svg
            width={width}
            height={height}
            viewBox='0 0 65 65'
            fill={fillColor}
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
            className={className}
            transform={`rotate(${rotateCenter}, 65, 65)`}
        >
            <circle
                cx='32.5'
                cy='32.5'
                r='31.5'
                stroke={strokeColor}
                strokeWidth={strokeWidth}
                className={className2}
            />
            <path
                d='M30.116 39H32.816L27.956 26.238H25.076L20.18 39H22.808L23.87 36.084H29.054L30.116 39ZM26.462 28.992L28.226 33.816H24.698L26.462 28.992ZM40.7482 39H43.5202L40.7842 33.78C42.4582 33.294 43.5022 31.944 43.5022 30.162C43.5022 27.948 41.9182 26.238 39.4342 26.238H34.4482V39H36.9502V34.086H38.2462L40.7482 39ZM36.9502 31.944V28.398H38.9662C40.2262 28.398 40.9642 29.1 40.9642 30.18C40.9642 31.224 40.2262 31.944 38.9662 31.944H36.9502Z'
                fill={fillColor2}
                className={className3}
            />
        </svg>
    );
};
```

- As you can see, there are three separate className parameters (1, 2, 3) abstracted: (1) className for `<svg>...</svg>`, property `JSX.IntrinsicElements.svg: SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>`; (2) className2 for `<circle />` property `JSX.IntrinsicElements.circle: SVGProps<SVGCircleElement>`; (3) className3 for `<path />` property JSX.IntrinsicElements.path: SVGProps.
- Notice that `const ArIcon: SvgIcon = ({ ... }): JSX.Element => {...}` is indeed a JSX.Element. Therefore, the `<svg></svg>` itself and any children (circles, paths, etc) are all `JSX.IntrinsicElements`, each allowed to have its own unique `className`. These `className` calls were added manually to the svg, as was the transform call (to rotate the icon inline elsewhere).
- the `JSX Attribute` className of `JSX.IntrinsicElements` is defined as follows

```
SVGAttributes<T>.className?: string | undefined
```

- Each JSX.IntrinsicElement is entitled to a className property. Have 100 paths and a circle within an svg? you can have 102 classNames that can be parameterized via abstraction.
- Now for the best part. The following is from a file in my portfolio, I tinkered with abstracting svg parameters to make it play nicely with Dark mode toggling (`use-dark-mode`) and screen-width dependent icon rendering (`@artsy/fresnel`). You can import this Icon globally and call parameters inline within each JSX.Element without any props passing

```
import { ArIcon } from 'components/svg-icons';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { Media } from 'components/window-width';
import { Fragment } from 'react';
import DarkMode from 'components/lead-dark-mode';

const ArIconConditional = (): JSX.Element => {
    const arIconXs: JSX.Element = (
        <Media at='xs'>
            <Link href='/'>
                <a
                    className='container block pl-portfolio pt-portfolio justify-between mx-auto w-full min-w-full '
                    id='top'
                    aria-label='top'
                >
                    <ArIcon width='18vw' height='18vw' className='transition-all transform translate-y-90' 
 className2='transition-all duration-1000 delay-200 transform' className3='text-secondary fill-secondary' />
                </a>
            </Link>
        </Media>
    );

    const arIconSm: JSX.Element = (
        <Media at='sm'>
            <Link href='/'>
                <a
                    className='container block pl-portfolio pt-portfolio justify-between mx-auto w-full min-w-full '
                    id='top'
                    aria-label='top'
                >
                    <ArIcon width='15vw' height='15vw' className='' className2='' className3='' />
                </a>
            </Link>
        </Media>
    );

    const arIconMd: JSX.Element = (
        <Media at='md'>
            <Link href='/'>
                <a
                    className='container block pl-portfolio pt-portfolio justify-between mx-auto w-full min-w-full '
                    id='top'
                    aria-label='top'
                >
                    <ArIcon width='12.5vw' height='12.5vw' className='' className2='' className3='' />
                </a>
            </Link>
        </Media>
    );

    const arIconDesktop: JSX.Element = (
        <Media greaterThan='md'>
            <Link href='/'>
                <a
                    className='container block pl-portfolio pt-portfolio justify-between mx-auto w-full min-w-full '
                    id='top'
                    aria-label='top'
                >
                    <ArIcon width='10vw' height='10vw' className='' className2='' className3='' />
                </a>
            </Link>
        </Media>
    );

    const ArIconsCoalesced = (): JSX.Element => (
        <Fragment>
            <div className='relative block justify-between lg:w-auto lg:static lg:block lg:justify-start transition-all w-full min-w-full col-span-5'>
                {arIconXs}
                {arIconSm}
                {arIconMd}
                {arIconDesktop}
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className='select-none relative z-1 justify-between pt-portfolioDivider navbar-expand-lg grid grid-cols-6 min-w-full w-full container overflow-y-hidden overflow-x-hidden transform'>
                <ArIconsCoalesced />
                <div className='pt-portfolio'>
                    <DarkMode />
                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    );
};

export default ArIconConditional;
```

- This [project](https://asross-portfolio.vercel.app/) uses tailwindcss and React's Next.js framework. That said, what if I wanted the `JSX.IntrinsicElement` circle encompassing the Icon to pulse on mobile only? add tailwind's `animate-pulse` to `className2` as follows

```
// ...
    const arIconXs: JSX.Element = (
        <Media at='xs'>
            <Link href='/'>
                <a
                    className='container block pl-portfolio pt-portfolio justify-between mx-auto w-full min-w-full '
                    id='top'
                    aria-label='top'
                >
                    <ArIcon width='18vw' height='18vw' className='transition-all transform translate-y-90' 
 className2='transition-all duration-1000 delay-200 transform animate-pulse' className3='text-secondary fill-secondary' />
                </a>
            </Link>
        </Media>
    );
// ...
```

- The  `fill-primary` call is a css variable defined for both `.dark-mode` and `.light-mode` css classes which are then passed to `:root` and activated on the toggling of darkMode by the client (`onChange={darkMode.toggle}`).
- So, `onClick={darkMode.enable}` triggers the icon to change its fillColor and strokeColor values as a function of css variables. Utilizing React's `FC` to parameterize props via abstraction produces a truly remarkable degree of granular control. Customizing SVGs using inline calls at the JSX.Element level globally has never been so seamless.
- darkMode.disable

[image: darkMode.disable]

- darkMode.enable

[image: darkMode.enable]

- Check out my [recent DEV post](https://dev.to/asross311/hacking-the-fontawesome-library-for-custom-icon-integration-with-nextjs-and-typescript-1em8) if hacking the react-fontawesome library using typescript and next to create custom fontawesome SVG Icons that persist to production and are unchanged by library version updates piques your interest.

Cheers

Comment: This is seriously awesome. Well done 

Comment: that typescript is bad, and is actually what the OP is trying to solve here 

Answer (score 2):

This worked in the case of using Next.js

```
declare module "*.svg" {
    import {ReactElement, SVGProps} from "react";
    const ReactComponent: (props: SVGProps<SVGElement>) => ReactElement;
    export {ReactComponent}
}
```

Comment: Please describe your answer more. Simple code is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```js
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: React.ElementType<React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'svg'>>;
  export default content;
}
```

Gabriels answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65326058/11313928 lacks `ref` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Since NextJS was overriding my custom.d.ts exported `*.svg` module, I ended up  importing all svg files into one `Icons.ts` file, and typing them as follows:

```
import { ReactElement, SVGProps } from 'react';

import Rotate from './360.svg';
import Clock from './clock.svg';
import Close from './close.svg';
import Discord from './discord.svg';
import Github from './github.svg';
import Hamburger from './hamburger.svg';
import Location from './location.svg';
import Logo from './logo.svg';
import MapPin from './map-pin.svg';
import Medium from './medium.svg';

const importedIcons = {
  Rotate,
  Clock,
  Close,
  Discord,
  Github,
  Hamburger,
  Location,
  Logo,
  MapPin,
  Medium,
};

type IconName = keyof typeof importedIcons;
type ReactComponent = (props: SVGProps<SVGElement>) => ReactElement;
export default importedIcons as Record<IconName, ReactComponent>;
```

Then when I want to use an icon, I can import it as follows, and intellisense picks up svg prop values.

```
import Icons from '~assets/icons/Icons';

...
<Icons.Rotate fill="green" stroke="purple" height={10} />
...
```

Not the default configuration, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

Hexagon.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
const Hexagon= (props:any) => (
    <svg
        id="Layer_1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px"
        y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 40 40"
        style={{
          enableBackground: "new 0 0 512 512",
        }}
        xmlSpace="preserve"
        width={props.size ? props.size : 40}
        height={props.size ? props.size : 40}
        fill={"currentColor"}
        {...props}
    >
        <path
          points="25.045,128 256,0 486.955,128 486.955,384 256,512 25.045,384 "
          d="M1.957 10L20 0L38.043 10L38.043 30L20 40L1.957 30Z"
        />
    </svg>
);

export default Hexagon;
```

Then import your component and use

```
<Hexagon /> {/* this one will be default size (40) and default to whatever is the currentColor */}
```

or

```
<Hexagon size={100} style={{ color: "green" }} /> {/* this one will be larger and green */}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution for `next  > 11` (resolving `declare module '*.svg'` not working)

You can add static type definitions in a `*.d.ts` file (as suggested in [Gabrie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65326058/11190169)):

```
// e.g. global.d.ts

declare module '*.svg' {
    import type { ReactElement, SVGProps } from 'react';
    const content: (props: SVGProps<SVGElement>) => ReactElement;
    export default content;
}
```

The problem with this is that next adds its own image static types which overrides those you define. To disable these image static types forced by next, add `images.disableStaticImages` in your `next.config.js` like this:

```js
const nextConfig = {
    // .....
    images: {
        disableStaticImages: true,
    },
    // .....
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

and run `yarn dev` to apply

Comment: I've got `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.` without `disableStaticImages: true` and `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders` with. Any suggestions what can I do?